# Regular expression for equal number of 0 and 1

Tags: regex

How to find regular expression with equal number of 1 and 0.
I am also interested in how you think such solution ?

example:
should match : 1100, 00100111 , 01 .
shouldn't match: 110 , 0, 11001.

I need regular expression which gives set of all such string .
If length of string in set given by regular expression in `2n` then number of `0s` should be equal to number `1s = n`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to match. Please provide examples of strings that should match and of strings that shouldn't match.

Comment: Also, please state which language are you using, or if you are talking about regular expressions in the computer science sense.

Comment: Regular expressions don't "give set of all such string". They define a pattern. If you need to generate all possible matching strings, that's not a job for regex. Also, please put the `[homework]` tag instead of `[exam]` if it's some sort of an assignment, and also add a tag for the programming language you are using. You can do it by pressing the [edit] link.

Comment: I hear the `[homework]` tag is also being phased out now.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @LevLevitsky, a computer-theoretic regular expression does define a set. The regular expression is just a short-hand method for defining the set of strings that match it.

Comment: @dbaupp If you mean that defining a pattern is in some way equivalent to defining a set of strings that match it, then I understand and agree, but I don't see how it's useful if any further processing of (or even listing) the elements of the set is required.

Answer (score 15):

It is not possible to generate a regular expression for the language L = (0,1) (same number of 1s and 0s).

This is not a regular language, so cannot be described with a regular expression. It's not regular because an automaton which accepts it would need differing amounts of memory depending on the length of the input. A regular language is one which uses constant memory, regardless of the length of the input.

The language you describe can be generated by a Context Free Grammar, but not a regular expression.

The following CFG generates strings where the numbers of 0s and the number of 1s are equal. If S is any word in the language:

```
S -> SS
S -> 0S1
S -> 1S0
S -> ε (the empty word)
```

For this language you need a stack, and a pushdown automaton could be designed to accept it, or a Turing machine.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible with regular grammar (finite state automaton) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

Comment: I just saw this old answer since it comes to be upvoted, today i would anwser differently this is still true for basic regex, but possible with a recursive regex `/^(|0(?1)1)$/`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a regex pattern for the .NET engine that does satisfy your needs. See it in action at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/F6ZJOi).

```
^((?(D)(?!))(?<C>1)|(?(D)(?!))(?<-C>0)|(?(C)(?!))(?<D>0)|(?(C)(?!))(?<-D>1))*(?(C)(?!))(?(D)(?!))$
```

It works by using two stacks, using one (C) if there are curretly more 1s than 0s and the other one (D) if there are more zeroes than ones.

Not pretty, definitely not usable, but it works. (Ha!)

Comment: That is one filthy hack. I take my hat off to you sir, the runtime of this must really suck.

Comment: Thanks! =) I am proud to never use this .. thing.. in production code. But runtime-wise it should be ok, O(n) for string length n, since it does not do much backtracking. I've seen worse regular expressions.

Comment: I managed to shorten this to `^(((?<C>0)|(?<-C>1))+(?(C)(?!))|((?<D>1)|(?<-D>0))+(?(D)(?!)))$`. Numbered groups allow me to shorten it further: `^((?<-2>1)|(?<-3>0)|(0)|(1))*(?(2)(?!))(?(3)(?!))$` (doesn't work with named groups because the group is defined after it is used).

Answer (score 1):

While this is not possible with a regular grammar as stated in another answer, it should be relatively easy to scan the string, increment a counter for each `1` and decrement it for each `0`. If the final count is 0, then the number of `0`s and `1`s is equal (modulo 2^wordsize - watching out for overflow would make it a little trickier, but depending on whether there are other assumptions that can be made regarding the input, that may not be necessary).