# RegEx to match a binary number with even number of 0s

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working to create a regex to match a binaries with an even number of zeros.

For example, it should match numbers like:

```
001
1010
100100
```

But it shouldn't match:

```
0010
10001
00101
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(([0]{1})+)
```

I will really highly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What makes you think that regex is the right tool for this job?

Comment: I know that could be something that fits better to this, but it is a requirement for course I'm working now, and I do have basic Knowledge about regex.

Comment: Regex is not suited for counting tasks because it's a regular language. This means it has no memory and can't hold state of previous counts. `s.replace(/[^0]/g, "").length % 2 === 0` works nicely but it's probably not permitted if the course is requiring a regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for equal number of 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497514/regular-expression-for-equal-number-of-0-and-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not the best way, you can use a regex for this, searching for pairs of `0`'s in the string and asserting that there are no other `0` characters in the string outside those pairs (thus there must be an even number of `0`'s):

```
^(?:[^0]*0[^0]*0)+[^0]*$
```

```js
const strs = [
  '1010',
  '100100',
  '0010',
  '10001',
  '00101',
  '001',
  '1001',
  '100',
  '101'
]

strs.map(s => console.log(s + ': ' + /^(?:[^0]*0[^0]*0)+[^0]*$/.test(s)));
```