# how can I design a grammer for strings with equal numbers of a and b?

Tags: context-free-grammar

A context-free grammar for strings with equal numbers of a and b？
how can I do it and can you tell me the process?
Thanks very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297609/1566221

Comment: Here's some more readable duplicates from [cs.se], which is really a better place for questions like this which are not programming questions. https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/103628/4416. And https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22729/4416. There are undoubtedly others, since it's a standard exercise.